# Getting 401 (Unauthorized) when deleting data from loopback?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm having a model called companyUsers when I make a GET request I get all the companyUsers data. But when I make a DELETE or PUT request I get 401 (Unauthorized) error.

I made a DELETE request by method provided by loopback-angularjs-sdk like this

```
BaseUser.companyUser.destroy({
    id:recruiterId
});
```

please guide me into this.

Comment: You need to check the server side code. Also, improve your question. I cannot know what is wrong if you cant provide the code that handles your DELETE / PUT request.

Comment: @callmekatootie i've updated the code please help me into this.

Comment: Think about it yourself. Just by looking at the above code, can I really make out what is wrong? As mentioned, the issue lies on the server side. Paste the entire code - right from the request handler to the controller / model functions that respond to your request.

Comment: Check your ACL.
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access
 Try using destroyById or deleteById from angularjs sdk. I am not sure that destroy method is provided.

Comment: As stated by the rest of the people here, can you provide a link to a test project on GitHub? See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Reporting-issues#bug-report

Answer (score 0):

This is caused mainly due to the permission setting of the model. Try giving all the permissions to owner and see if you can delete.